# How do I start tty from the command-line?

Tags: tty, command

I would like to know what command launches tty from the command-line. I would like to know as I am using Plasma 5 and am fiddling around with my keyboard shortcuts and if I know what launches tty from the command-line I should be able to create a custom shortcut for it for Plasma 5.

Comment: Are you looking for Ctrl+F1?

Comment: Nope, I wanted the command-line command, not the keyboard command. I knew the keyboard shortcut for it, for me it is `Ctrl+Alt+F1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This requires sudo priviledges:

```
sudo chvt 1
```